# When someone phrases a question awkwardly to elicit a wrong response

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms

I'm looking for a phrase that describes the situation when someone asks a question in a way to elicit an incorrect response. For example:

> Alice: Hey, Bob, have you never done drugs?
>
> Bob: Nope!
>
> Alice: So you have done drugs, then?
>
> Bob: Argh, Alice! You know what I meant. That was such a ___ question!

Or something along those lines. I don't care much whether the word describes the question, or the situation, or maybe it's a verb describing what Alice did.

Comment: Trick/twisted/weird/stupid question?

Comment: Misleading is my #1 choice for that example.

Comment: They are sometimes called *questions of the "have you stopped beating your wife" variety*.

Comment: A "**gotcha**" question might be used informally.

Comment: A loaded question? https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/loaded-question

Answer (score 14):

A "trick question" is a question where the words are arranged in such a way as to produce an incorrect answer.

**Trick question** — [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/trick-question)

> a question that makes you believe you should answer it in a particular way, when the real question is hidden or there is no right answer

Answer (score 3):

If the question is posed in good faith then it's a **poorly phrased question** (couldn't [resist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19280/whats-the-correct-response-to-poorly-phrased-questions)). If the awkward phrasing was intentional and the "wrong" answer is actually the desired outcome, then it's a **[trick question](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trick%20question)**.

> a deceptive question that is intended to make one give an answer that is not correct or that causes difficulty

**Deceptive** (above) underlines the intentionality of the trick: *that was such a deceptive question!*

> Would you eat a slab of muscular tissue from a corpse? ...No? Well, I
>   guess I'll have this juicy steak all for myself then.

(this trick actually appears in some Heinlein novel featuring Lazarus Long, but I can't remember which).

You can also ask a question in a "correct" way but using [loaded language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_language), leading to a **[loaded question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question)**.

A [classic example](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wife-beating_question) is, I believe, *have you stopped beating your wife?*.

Comment: I feel like you have these backwards.  "Have you stopped beating your wife?" is more accurately describe as a loaded question, since any (normal) answer implicitly affirms an unsubstantiated assumption, which is the "real" goal of the question.  The question doesn't much care what your answer is, and so isn't trying to trick the responder into giving an incorrect response, but rather the point is to trick them into giving any response at all.  The steak question is an intentionally deceptive phrasing meant to illicit a mistaken response, which is more what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I agree with @zibadawatimmy it looks like you have them backwards.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**[inveigle](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inveigle)**

> to persuade (someone) to do something in a clever or deceptive way
>
> to get (something) in a clever or deceptive way

Comment: How would you use that in the OP's sample sentence?

Comment: @KristinaLopez I was responding to the last request in the post, "I don't care much whether the word describes the question, or the situation, or maybe it's a verb describing what Alice did."

Comment: Gotcha.  I was curious...and I'm a fan of that word. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may also say that Alice was being [**captious**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/captious)

> *adjective* **Intended to entrap or confuse, as in an argument.**

It comes for the latin word [captios](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/captio#Latin)

> ***captiō*** f (genitive captiōnis); third declension
>       deception, fraud, deceit
>       quibble
>       catch

Answer (score 0):

A [*Smart-Alecky*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smart%20aleck) question:

Definition of *Smart-Aleck* (via merriam-webster online):

> an obnoxiously conceited and self-assertive person with pretensions to smartness or cleverness

Example:

> some smart aleck in the audience kept shouting clever insults at the nervous speaker